# IE не понимает шрифт

Tags: html, css

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'MyriadPro-Cond';
    src: url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.svg') format('svg');
}
```

Так я объявляю шрифт и он, этот гадкий IE, не понимает, чего я от него хочу! Что делать, подскажите.

Comment: А ие то какой?;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Описание @font-face](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face)

Можно для IE попробовать отделить, чтобы не было путаницы:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style>
    /* только для Internet Explorer */
    @font-face {
       font-family:'MyriadPro-Cond';
       src: url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.eot');
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
  <style>
    /* для всех остальных браузеров */
    @font-face {
      font-family:'MyriadPro-Cond';
      src: local('☺'), url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.svg') format('svg');
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

А я бы предложил заюзать [гугл шрифты](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/webfonts/), там и [примерчики](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html#Quick_Start) есть. И, кстати, их даже можно сделать автономными.

Сам использую RaphaelJS ([print](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print)) в связке с [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/).

Comment: Куфон - это уже прошлый век, да и отрисовывать шрифты канвасом - это по меньшей мере глупое расходование ресурсов.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, я написал, что в связке с куфоном, если быть точном, то пользую только их генератор. 
А, во-вторых, не канвасом, а SVG и VML, в зависимости от браузера.

Comment: Всё, что предложили, всё не понимает,опера сафари фф хром работают хорошо а этот не понимает!

Comment: Я надеюсь Вы там не под 6ой пытаетесь это всё натянуть? Например, у меня в IE8, вот это работает на ура:

http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace:select

и это:

http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html#Quick_Start

Comment: Да и это, в принципе, тоже работает: http://raphaeljs.com/fonts.html

Если кириллицу пытаетесь прикрутить, то и шрифты, соответственно, нужно брать кириллические.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face{  
font-family: "Sft";  
src : url("28 Days Later.ttf"); 
}  
a {  
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: inherit;  
    font-size: 36px;  
    font-family: Sft;   
}
```

Comment: Всё, что предложили, всё не понимает,опера сафари фф хром работают хорошо а этот не понимает!